# Python 3D plotting of measurement data

Tags: python, 3d, plot

I have captured 3D measurement data on a sphere (this is an antenna radiation pattern, so the measurement antenna captured the radiation intensity from each phi,theta direction and logged this value as a function of phi,theta).

I am having great difficulty getting the data represented. 
I have tried multiple options. This is the last one I am now trying:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nElevationPoints = 16
nAzimuthPoints = 40
stepSizeRad = 0.05 * np.pi
def r(phi,theta):
    radius = 1
    return radius

phi = np.arange(0,nAzimuthPoints*stepSizeRad,stepSizeRad)
theta = np.arange(0,nElevationPoints*stepSizeRad,stepSizeRad)

x = (r(phi,theta)*np.outer(r(phi,theta)*np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)))
y = (-r(phi,theta)*np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta)))
z = (r(phi,theta)*np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta)))

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

This code in itself is working, and it plots a sphere. Now the thing is, that in accordance with the measurement data, I would actually need the radius not be a constant "1", but corresponding with the radiation intensity measured. So it needs to be a function of phi,theta.

However, as soon as I change the "r" function to anything containing the phi or theta parameter, I get an error about operands that could not be broadcast.

If there's any work around that loops through phi,theta that would be perfectly fine as well.

But I'm stuck now, so I'd appreciate any help :-)

BTW, the reason I went for the above approach is because I couldn't make sense of how the x,y,z should be defined in order to be acceptable to the plot_surface function. 
I did manage to generate a scatter plot, by calculating the actual positions (x,y,z) from the phi,theta,intensity data, but this is only a representation by individual points and doesn't generate any well visible antenna radiation pattern plot. For this I assume that a contour plot would be better, but then again I am stuck at either the "r" function call or by understanding how x,y,z should be formatted (the documentation refers to x,y,z needing to be 2D-arrays, but this is beyond my comprehension as x,y,z usually are one dimensional arrays in themselves).

Anyway, looking forward to any help anyone may be willing to give.

-- EDIT --

With @M4rtini 's suggested changes I come to the following:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def r(phi,theta):
    r = np.sin(phi)**2
    return r


phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:201j, 0:np.pi:101j]

x = r(phi,theta)*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = r(phi,theta)*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r(phi,theta)*np.cos(phi)

intensity = phi * theta

obj = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=intensity, colormap='jet')
obj.enable_contours = True
obj.contour.filled_contours = True
obj.contour.number_of_contours = 20
mlab.show()
```

This works, thanks, @M4rtini, and I now am able to have a phi,theta dependent "r" function.
However, noted that the example now ensures phi and theta to be of the same length (due to the mgrid function). This is not the case in my measurement. When declaring phi and theta separately and of different dimensions, it doesn't work still. So I now will have a look into measurement interpolation.

Comment: You could take a look at numpy.fromfunc, it can convert a function into a function supporting broadcasting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (I wasn't aware of this function), but it doesn't seem to help. It only seems to work if  nElevationPoints is equal to nAzimuthPOints (which is not the case in my measurement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the exact answer you were looking for, but if you can accept using intensity values as a mapping of a color, this should work.
Actually, you could probably calculate a specific r here also. But i did not test that.
Using mayavi since it is, in my opinion, far superior than matplotlib for 3D.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
r = 1.0
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:200j, 0:2*np.pi:101j]

x = r*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r*np.cos(phi)

intensity = phi * theta

obj = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=intensity, colormap='jet')
obj.enable_contours = True
obj.contour.filled_contours = True
obj.contour.number_of_contours = 20
mlab.show()
```

Output of example script, now this is in a interactive gui. so you can rotate, translate, scale as you please. And even interactively manipulate the data, and the representation options.
[image: Output of example script]

Comment: Thanks @M4rtini ! I wasn't able to find the Mayavi lib for my windows python 2.6 installation though. I did see a huge 200MB+ executable including and for python 2.7.

Comment: Are you restricted by project limitations to use python 2.6?

Comment: Yes, I was actually (some libs not available beyond 2.6). However, because of your suggestions and my continued bumping into walls, I just opted for the Canopy package (couldn't get it installed under 2.6 myself...) and now have Mayavi with Python2.7 and will see how I solve the 2.6 lib dependencies later on ;-) 

BTW, I just made some good progress, and am now able to have a "proper" radiation plot. I only need to look into the "scalars" option when plotting to affect color in the plot, because now it is only z-axis dependent which it shouldn't be. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: if the r represent the measured value you can probably just set the scalar to r. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html Here is a long list of the interpolate functions scipy have to offer. interp2d or scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates looks like good options.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I probably couldn't have done it without your help, thanks so much. I got everything running to my liking now :-)